# Need solution in DAX measure in Power BI with dates and slicers

Tags: date, calendar, powerbi, dax

I Need a measure that will calculate sum of sales-plan divided by the number of days in month which is selected in slicer? to get daily sales-plan of that month

Then I need to multiply that daily sales-plan on the number of days which are selected in range slicer, to get the sum of that range

For example: I have selected the range from 01/01/21 - 07/01/21/ And I have a quota on January 310$

So I need a measure that will calculate 310/31 = 10, and then I need it to be multiplied by 7 days which is in slicer, and get 70

I am trying to apply this but getting wrong result:

```
VAR minselectdate = CALCULATE(MIN('calendar'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('calendar'))

VAR maxselectdate = CALCULATE(MAX('calendar'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('calendar'))

VAR StartPeriod = EOMONTH(minselectdate,-1)+1

VAR EndPeriod = EOMONTH(maxselectdate, 0)

VAR Currdate = LASTDATE('calendar'[Date])

VAR Plan = CALCULATE(SUM('Все_отчет1_Квоты'[Квота месяц]),DATESBETWEEN('calendar'[Date],StartPeriod,EndPeriod))

VAR datesperiod = COUNTROWS(DATESBETWEEN('calendar'[Date],StartPeriod,EndPeriod))

VAR planondate = DIVIDE(Plan,datesperiod)

VAR Result = ALCULATE(SUMX(VALUES('calendar'[Date]),planondate),DATESBETWEEN('calendar'[Date], minselectdate,Currdate))

Return

Result
```

Comment: I am trying to apply this but getting wrong result

Comment: What wrong result? What's the expected result? W/o looking at the data model, no one will be able to help you. Don't you realize that?

Comment: So I need a measure that will calculate 310/31 = 10, and then I need it to be multiplied by 7 days which is in slicer, and get 70

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a calendar table.  I will assume it has a relationship to your plan table, and has information on months.

If your filter is on Calendar[Date] and your calendar has monthYear information, you can do this all in a measure as so:

```
DailyPlanAmount = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Plan[PlanAmount] ) / COUNTROWS ( 'Calendar' ),
    ALL ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
    VALUES ( 'Calendar'[MonthYear] )
)
    * COUNTROWS ( 'Calendar' )
```

We do the sum of plan amounts and use the 'All' function to clear out any filters on date, replacing it with a filter on month.   Then we count out the rows (outside our filter) in the calendar table to get a number of days and multiply this against our result.

[image]